# how can i get the nearby products to current user location in recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am trying to build an application which the seller upload his product and the user could see them 
so I want the buyer to see the nearby products in recyclerView
I am using kotlin and firebase realtime database 
this is what I have tried

```
class owner : AppCompatActivity() {

          lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
          lateinit var geoFire: GeoFire
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner)
           val datbaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
           databaseReference = datbaseInstance.getReference("GOODS")
           val id1 =databaseReference.push().key.toString()
           floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            showDialogue(id1)
        }

// I used this code to get the products but it didn't work and didn't show anything 

        val geoQuery0 : GeoQuery = 
      geofire!!.queryAtLocation(GeoLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongtude), 
       7.0)
      geoQuery0.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener {
                override fun onKeyEntered(key: String, location: GeoLocation) {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Provider %s is within your search 
       range [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude))
                    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : 
          ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                productAdapt.clear()
                p0.children.forEach { children ->
                    val textMessss = children.getValue(uploadProduct::class.java)
                    val idd = textMessss?.id.toString()
                    productAdapt.add(
                        getProductAdapter(
                            this@owner,
                            children.getValue(uploadProduct::class.java)!!,
                            idd
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        })
                }


                override fun onKeyExited(key: String) {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Provider %s is no longer in the 
        search area", key))
                }

                override fun onKeyMoved(key: String, location: GeoLocation) {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Provider %s moved within the search 
           area to [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude))
                }

                override fun onGeoQueryReady() {


                    Log.i(TAG, "onGeoQueryReady")
                }

                override fun onGeoQueryError(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error: " + error)
                }
            })

         }
           fun showDialogue(id1:String) {
              val alertbilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialog)
              val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adding_product, null)
              alertbilder.setView(view)
              val alertdialogue = alertbilder.create()
              alertdialogue.show()

          view.add_btn.setOnClickListener { val uploadP = 

         uploadProduct(id1,name,price,desc,uid,longtude,latitude,productImageUrl 
          , nameOfShop)
               databaseReference.child(id1).setValue(uploadP)

                val geoRef = databaseReference.child(id1)
                geoFire = GeoFire(geoRef)
                geoFire.setLocation("geoFire", GeoLocation(latitude, longtude))}
             alertdialogue.dismiss()
            }
          }
```

this is my adapter for receiving data and show them in recyclerView

```
 class getProductAdapter( val context: Context, val uploadProduct: uploadProduct, val idd: String ) : 
   Item() {

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.nameOfProductR.text = uploadProduct.name
    viewHolder.priceOfProductR.text = uploadProduct.price
    viewHolder.descOfProductR.text =uploadProduct.desc
    val url =uploadProduct.image
    GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .into(viewHolder.productImage)
    }

    override fun getLayout() = R.layout.recycler_view_item

 }
```

and this is how the data look like on firebase

```
GOODS
    -M7Jr5Cb8bx97gtW5UCK
       desc: "It Is Product One "
       id: "M7Jr5Cb8bx97gtW5UCK"
       image: ""
       latitude: ""
       longTude: ""
       name: "Product 1"
       nameOfShop: ""
       price: "123"
       uidd: ""
       geoFire
         g: "9q8yywdgue"
         l
           0: 37.7853889
           1: -122.4056973
     -M7KDGxfWJ3rJgNZSZrJ
        desc: "Suwushd"
        id: "M7KDGxfWJ3rJgNZSZrJ"
        image: ""
        latitude: ""
        longTude: ""
        name: "Sueuu"
        nameOfShop: ""
        price: "26262"
        uidd: ""
        geoFire
          g: "9q8yywdgue"
          l
```

and this is the rules of the realtime database

```
{
    "rules": {
    "<GOODS>": {
      "$GOODS":{
      // Allow anyone to read the GeoFire index
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
   "geoFire":{
      // Index each location's geohash for faster querying
      ".indexOn": ["g"]
       }}},
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I expect the code will order the product by the nearby to current user location